# Sort by $natural in MongoDB with the official c# driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the official C# driver and I want to sort a collection by `$natural`.

I know for sorting by keys, I can use

```
collection.Find(query).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("Name"))
```

How do I sort with `$natural`?

Comment: Important note: There's no need to sort by ascending $natural order. That's the order MongoDB `naturally` returns results in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use sort descending by it. For example:

```
collection.Insert(new BsonDocument("x", 1));
collection.Insert(new BsonDocument("x", 2));
collection.Insert(new BsonDocument("x", 3));

foreach (var document in collection.FindAll()
    .SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("$natural"))) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(document.ToJson());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated Robert Stam's answer to something roughly equivalent, using the syntax for the 2.0 driver...

```
await collection.InsertOneAsync(new BsonDocument("x", 1));
await collection.InsertOneAsync(new BsonDocument("x", 2));
await collection.InsertOneAsync(new BsonDocument("x", 3));

foreach (
    var document in
        await
            collection.Find(_ => true)
                .Sort(new SortDefinitionBuilder<BsonDocument>().Descending("$natural"))
                .ToListAsync())
{
    Console.WriteLine(document.ToJson());
}
```